# Not able to parse html tags in DataTable row data

Tags: reactjs, datatables, html-react-parser

I am getting HTML tags in a single element for every cell of DataTables.
I want to Parse HTML tags also but till now, unable to do so.

I have already tried html-react-parser but it is parsing them into an array.

```
import Parse from "html-react-parser";

<Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {/* <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein (g)</TableCell> */}
            {props.tableData.HeadingData.map(el=>{
              return <TableCell align="right">{el}</TableCell>
            })}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow>
              {/* <TableCell align="right">{row}</TableCell> */}
              {row.map(el=>{
                console.log(Parse(el));
                return <TableCell align="right">{Parse(el)}</TableCell>
              })}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
```

```
"content":{
                "Title": "List Title",
                "HeadingData" :["Name", "Company", "City", "State"],
                "RowData" :[
                    ["Joe James", "Test Corp<br/>TestCorp", "Yonkers", "NY"],
                    ["John Walsh", "Test Corp", "Hartford", 1989],
                    ["Bob Herm", "Test Corp", "Tampa", "FL"],
                    ["James Houston", "Test Corp", "Dallas", "TX"],
                ]
            },
```

Above is the Table Data and if you see company has the html tags "Test Corp
TestCorp".

I am not able to parse it as it is returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Solved by converting each cell element into string before parsing through html-react-parser.

Comment: This solution works with my custom Table with Material ui since I am able to access single element.

Comment: Is it possible to parse html tags in a single element in mui-datatables?